# Autotools AC_SEARCH_LIBS finds the library, but doesn't add it to $LIBS

Tags: shared-libraries, autotools, dlopen

I am using autotools to configure and build my project which uses dlopen and its friends.

I've got the following snippet in my root `configure.ac`:

`AC_SEARCH_LIBS([dlopen], [dl dld], [], [
  AC_MSG_ERROR([unable to find the dlopen() function])
])`

which I got from https://autotools.io/autoconf/finding.html

The library is found by autotools:

`checking for library containing dlopen... -ldl`

However, the library doesn't appear to get added to `$(LIBS)` because:

`a_out_LDADD=-ldl`

works (i.e. project compiles, and runs), and

`a_out_LDADD=$(LIBS)`

does not (i.e. `undefined reference to 'dlopen'`)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

(Full disclosure, I'm the author of the linked documentation.)

Are you sure the `LIBS` variable is not getting somehow clobbered? You can check `config.log` to see what the final output is. I think the most common problem with this is a later line that goes `LIBS=${SOMEDEPS_LIBS}` without prepending the old `LIBS` value.

Also you should not need to do `_LDADD=$(LIBS)` because the latter is added by default to all linking commands.